# C++ operator[] syntax

Tags: c++, dictionary, operators, operator-overloading

Just a quick syntax question.  I'm writing a map class (for school).

If I define the following operator overload:

```
template<typename Key, typename Val> class Map {...
Val* operator[](Key k);
```

What happens when a user writes:

```
Map<int,int> myMap;
map[10] = 3;
```

Doing something like that will only overwrite a temporary copy of the [null] pointer at Key k.  Is it even possible to do:

```
map[10] = 3;
printf("%i\n", map[10]);
```

with the same operator overload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way it works with `std::map` is that, if the key doesn't exist, the map class will insert a default value and then return an lvalue (an assignable reference to the value associated with the key), so it can be assigned a new value.

So, in the following code sample, assuming `map` is empty, this will insert 10 into the map and associate it with a value of 3.

```
map[10] = 3;
```

With your custom map class, `operator[]` should first check if the Key k exists, and if not, insert a new key/value pair (using the default constructor of typename `Val`) into the map.  You can then return a reference to the Value associated with the new key, so the user can assign a value to it.  Note that this means that Val must be Assignable and have a default constructor.

This allows `operator[]` to be used both for insertion and lookup.  You should also overload a `const` version of `operator[]`, which of course only supports lookup.

Edit: I now noticed in your code that you are returning a pointer.  If you want to use the insert/lookup paradigm for `operator[]` used by std::map, it makes more sense to return a reference.  Returning a pointer gives you the advantage that you can examine the return value of `operator[]` for NULL to check if the key doesn't exist, but again, if you want `operator[]` to provide both lookup and insert functionality, a reference would be the way to go here.

Comment: so I should define my overload as
Val& operator[] (Key k); and ofc ensure that I initialize appropriately, even if there isn't anything there.

Comment: Thanks a bunch; kind of a shame that I have to make objects, even when it's not 'needed'.

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to do it that way. The [] operator is provided strictly for the class user's convenience. The user can always use normal find/insert functions.

Comment: Also, it's preferable to define your overload as: `Val& operator[] (const Key& k);` so you can pass k by reference, rather by value.